# Utilise jQuery plugin with ES6 import

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6, summernote

I've installed the jquery plugin [summernote](https://www.npmjs.com/package/summernote) using npm and it's within my node_modules directory.

I'm now trying to utilise the summernote function in much the same way as I was before when I was just loading the scripts within the html.

```
import { summernote } from 'summernote';

export default function () {
    const summernote = $('.editor');
    summernote.summernote();
}
```

I can't get past the above code throwing `summernote.summernote is not a function`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting

Comment: `import { summernote } from 'summernote'; declare var $;` is not valid syntax

Comment: Which bundler are you using?

Comment: A jQuery plugin that does install a method to the global jQuery prototype would not export anything. Are you sure you did import jQuery and `$` refers to jQuery? `import $ from 'jquery'; import 'summernote';` should do.

Comment: That seems to have worked although jquery seemed to be working fine. It's only when I tried to access a plugin through a jquery obj would I get an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This module doesn't export anything useful](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/blob/develop/dist/summernote.js#L18) (like it should be expected from jQuery plugin package).

Imported `summernote` isn't used, and unused imported member makes an import a noop.

It should be

```
import 'summernote';
```